# I can't create react apps! canvas related issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, canvas, npx

My laptop is M1 macbook pro. The node version is 15.4.1. The npm version is 7.0.15.

After I used this cmd `npx create-react-app my-app`, it returned this:

[image]

I've tried a lot, but always got the same issue. I think the problem is with "canvas". But I have no idea how to solve it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the installer need to find head files of some dependencies in `/usr/local/include/`, but the head files of dependencies installed by arm brew is in `/opt/homebrew/include` and the installer can't find them.

One solution is reinstalling brew under Rosetta 2, then installing related dependencies (pkg-config cairo, libpng, jpeg, giflib, pango).

Another solution is creating symbolic link in `/usr/local/include/` linking to related head files in `/opt/homebrew/include`
(For example, `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/jpeglib.h /usr/local/include/jpeglib.h`) (I don't think it's an elegant solution but at least it works).

(I also install xcode but I'm not sure whether it has something to do with this problem.)